# Atiyah's remark on Tate-Schafarevich & Poincare conj.?

Tags: ho.history-overview

Peter Woit quoted Atiyah in his blog ( http://scilogs.spektrum.de/hlf/sir-michael-atiyah-unity-mathematics-physics/ ) : "Tate-Shafarevich conjecture might have something to do with the 4-dimensional smooth Poincare conjecture" - it would be great if one could read more about that idea(s)?

Comment: Do you know if there is video or a transcript of the talk?  If Atiyah is just speculating, then it is unlikely that anything substantial is written up.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278288/exotic-4-spheres-and-thetate-shafarevich-group