# Exotic 4-spheres and the Tate-Shafarevich Group

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, algebraic-number-theory, 4-manifolds

The title is  a talk given by Sir M. Atiyah in a conference with the following abstract:

**I will     explain     a   deep    analogy     between     4-dimensional   smooth geometry (Donaldson  theory) and     algebraic   number  theory.     In  this    analogy the     group   of  exotic 4-spheres    is  the     counterpart     of  the     Tate-Shafarevich group**

I'm extremely curious about the analogy and I can't find a document on the subject. Would someone enlighten us about this analogy ?

**Edit** I found a [link](http://www.connes70.fudan.edu.cn/Data/View/213) of the conference with many videos, and Atiyah's is now uploaded too!

Comment: Link to conference:http://www.connes70.fudan.edu.cn/Assets/userfiles/sys_eb538c1c-65ff-4e82-8e6a-a1ef01127fed/files/Workshop2.pdf

Comment: Atiyah seems to be making a number of these types of talks.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think I don't know how to understand your comment. Could you be more precise ?

Comment: Note it's not known whether homotopy 4-spheres form a group. This is related to the Schoenflies conjecture, as Ian Agol points out here: https://lamington.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/scharlemann-on-schoenflies/#comment-1769

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253577/atiyahs-paper-on-complex-structures-on-s6, https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/mathematician-sir-michael-atiyah-88-hopes-to-prove-himself-again-with-new-solution-27b3jrhl7 (register wall)

Comment: Better link for the second one http://mathoverflow.net/questions/273828/

Comment: To quote from the Times article: _he has set about tackling one of the greatest challenges in maths: to produce a simple proof of the Feit-Thompson theorem, ..._

_The theorem runs to 255 pages of densely argued text. Sir Michael ... has reduced it to 12 pages, simply explained. This week he sent it to 15 experts in the field and is waiting for their reaction._

_He knows he faces an army of sceptics. Even his own family think he would be better off enjoying a quiet retirement. But he cannot accept that age is an insuperable barrier._

Comment: Atiyah's video is now uploaded! Now if only someone could solve another Atiyah mystery and tell me what he said last year about the galois group of the octonions lying at the heart of the unification of the forces of physics .... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250715/atiyah-on-the-galois-group-of-the-octonions-and-physics